# QGIS WMS highlight

Tags: qgis, wms, qgis-server, qgis-web-client

In QGIS web client in layer search we have option to highlight layer using QGIS WMS highlight:

```
highlightFeature: false,
highlightFeature (optional): use QGIS WMS highlight instead of QGIS WMS selection if enabled
```

but unfortunately I have no idea how to make it work. It adds HIGHLIGHT_GEOM, HIGHLIGHT_STYLE and other HIGHLIGHT_* params to the URL, but the server doesn't highlight these geometries in any way.

It works perfectly in Kanton Solothurn `[http://www.sogis1.so.ch/wsgi/webgisLauncher.wsgi?uuid=3a44cf87-3213-4a2f-a8c8-171c7f97a300][1]` (server returns highlighted geometry based on these params.

Comment: it is not clear to me whether the QGIS server you are sending your request to is your QGIS server, or just some random server you are requesting data from.  Note the `if enabled` comment.  If your URL has those parameters added, but the server doesn't do any highlighting, then it appears that highlighting is not enabled on the server.